# Python equivalent of boxcox in R

Tags: python, scipy, regression, transformation

The `boxcox()` function in R maximizes the log-likelihood of a linear model parameterized by λ ([link 1](https://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/_static/files/R_html/Transformations.html)).

I am looking for a Python equivalent. I know there is a `scipy.stats.boxcox` function, but it applies the transformation without the linear model context. I guess it maximizes its own log-likelihood function ([link 2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox_llf.html)).

I do not see any way to pass my `statsmodels` model into `scipy.stats.boxcox` as an argument, nor I want to write custom loss functions for `statsmodels` optimization routine. This is supposed to be a toy example for non-programmers. Does anyone know how this is done in Python? I am sure people have done it.